# IIS Redirecting non-WWW to WWW along with HTTP to HTTPS ISSUE

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-8.5

I want to redirect non-WWW to WWW along with HTTP to HTTPS in IIS 8.5. if users type http://example.com, http://www.example.com, or https://example.com, they all redirect to https://www.example.com.

This is my web.config file

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite
```

Please note that in IIS i have ONLY 1 binding which is example.com, The problem is : for all the urls it redirects to https://www.example.com BUT the start page of IIS appears not my Default.aspx, and When i type https://www.example.com/Default.aspx it gives 404 Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to bind each hostname to a website. Any hostnames not specifically bound to a website (or the servers IP address) will be handled by the Default Website in IIS (binding `*` - meaning any hostname not bound to a running Website).

A nice easy setup is to create 2 Websites in IIS (lets call them `Application` and `Rewrites`) - one to host your application, a second to handle rewriting other domains to your primary domain. Any domain you bind to the `Rewrite` Website will redirect its traffic to https://www.example.com.

###`Application` Website

- Bind just your applications hostname `www.example.com` on port 443 (SSL only)
- Deploy your application to this webroot

###`Rewrite` Website

- Create a new Website in IIS, and create a new folder for its webroot.
- Bind `example.com` on port 443 and port 80. Also bind `www.example.com` on port 80 only.

Create a web.config in the `Rewrite` Website webroot folder as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect any traffic to Primary hostname" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>        
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any traffic accessing http://example.com, https://example.com, or http://www.example.com will be redirected to https://www.example.com (including any path/query string)

NOTE: You could use the default website as the `Rewrite` website, or move the wildcard `*` binding from the default website to a new `Rewrite` website - to redirect any domain to your https://www.example.com - however this is bad practise / not advised.

**Pre-requisite:** To use this solution you'll need to install the [IIS URL Rewrite extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if you don't have it installed already.

Comment: Smith i installed the ssl certificate on AWS load balancer, should i install it on the IIS instead to be able t o bind the hostname on port 443

Comment: You didn't mention a load balancer in your question. Above solution I assumed all config was being done in iis. Please update your question to include details of your load balancer and I will update my answer

Comment: i will mark this answer as correct answer to help others who might face this problem, and will ask new one

Comment: I added a link to the URL Rewrite extension for future readers.