# web.config many domain aliases, two sites in one IIS VHOST. Arghhhhhhh

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I have googled. I have tried a thousand variations found on SO, but to no avail.

Here's my problem:

One vhost on IIS. Ten domains point to it. The application is set to use two hostnames of a single domain, but all the other aliases should redirect to the main site1.domain.com.

site1.domain.com (main site/host.domain)
site2.domain.com (second application running in the same vhost)

What I don't want to do is set up a bunch of vhosts. I'm trying to get this all running in a single vhost and redirect everything in web.config.

This is the latest version of `web.config` which is in an infinite loop. I understand why, but I can't fix the second rule to work.

My idea:

1. Look for the "second" hostname first and sort that out, since it is a literal, then redirect that to its home. By itself, it works just fine.
2. Once that's done, look for anything that is not site1.domain.com and redirect it to site1.domain.com.

Everything needs to redirect to SSL, of course.

Yes, I know I'm being too literal, but I simply cannot think or read my way through what logic I need.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="site2 HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(site2.)?domain.com" ignoreCase="true" />
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="site1 HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(https://site1)?.domain.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://site1.domain.com{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

Comment: How's about a single rule, with a single condition based on protocol then use the host variable as the destination url so it covers all bound domains?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, I need to host *two* separate hostnames so don't I need a minimum of two actions? If URL = site2, go here + SSL. If URL = everything else, go to site1.

Comment: Would a 2nd vhost be acceptable? That would be much simpler logic. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842621/iis-redirecting-non-www-to-www-along-with-http-to-https-issue/49845350#49845350

Answer (score 0):

Theres a problem with your web.config.  `pattern="(https://site1)?.domain.com"` will never match `{HTTP_HOST}` as it contains the hostname only ie: `site1.domain.com` (you can use 2 conditions with `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"`like the previous rule).

Personally I'd recommend using an additional dedicated vhost to handle rewrites (See my answer: [IIS Redirecting non-WWW to WWW along with HTTP to HTTPS ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842621/iis-redirecting-non-www-to-www-along-with-http-to-https-issue/49845350#49845350)). It's simpler and your primary sites app pool does not have to do any redirects it only handles requests for the ssl bindings for the sites your hosting which just seems like a good idea. (I expect it's marginally faster as your app won't have to evaluate the redirects on every request - but that's an assumption)

Comment: Thanks. It's disappointing that this can't be resolved in a single VHOST, so I will go this route.