# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found-Redirect non-www to https with iis

Tags: iis

I am setting up a non-www to https redirection for a website, for example, redirecting [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to https://example.com. However, when I do this, I encounter the 404 error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to change https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI} to my own domain name

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and WWW to non-WWW, please try the following rule:

```
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

Comment: No, it is always the same issue : "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.é

Comment: when I change it to www,examples.com

Comment: When you get a 404 error, what is the URL in your browser's address bar? How did you set up the bindings on your website? Did you bind the hostname "example.com"? Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842621/iis-redirecting-non-www-to-www-along-with-http-to-https-issue

Comment: You can also try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！